# BGP: What are the considerations for announcing a RIPE block in ARIN-controlled territory?

Tags: bgp, arin, ripe, routing-registry

We have an ASN and are considering leasing a addresses under RIPE's jurisdiction (because they cost less). However, we are in North America and would announce those addresses via BGP to our providers in the US.

Is this allowed?  Of course technically it's fine, BGP doesn't care, but are there regulations to follow here?

What are the considerations for announcing a RIPE block in ARIN-controlled territory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no practical obstacle to using RIPE number resources outside of its region.  RIPE also has the most mature database/tooling and is generally easier to work with than e.g. ARIN.

On the flip-side, AFRINIC and its ISP community do work to avoid having its IP addresses used outside of Africa.  That's the only RIR that's really been concerned with regional boundaries from a practical perspective.